# Parallel.Foreach blocking confusion

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Per my understanding the Parallel.Foreach block the calling thread until it completes. 
However, the below code behave differently  --

```
private void TestParallel()
{
            Console.WriteLine("Starting TestParallelForEach");
            TestParallelForEach();
            Console.WriteLine("Ending TestParallelForEach");
}

public void TestParallelForEach()
{
            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            urls.Add("http://www.google.com");
            urls.Add("http://www.yahoo.com");
            urls.Add("http://www.microsoft.com");
            urls.Add("http://www.facebook.com");

            var t = Parallel.ForEach(
                urls,
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 },
                async url =>
                {
                    string x = await openUrlAsync(url);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Url {0}, result {1}", url, x));
                });

            Console.WriteLine(" Parallel.ForEach Completed - " + t.IsCompleted);
   }



private async Task<string> openUrlAsync(string url)
{
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //var result = await client.GetAsync("http://webcode.me");
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        string re = result.StatusCode.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Got response from Url {0}", url));
        return re;
 }
```

However, the output of the above code is as follows -- 

 Starting TestParallelForEach 

 Parallel.ForEach Completed - True

 Ending TestParallelForEach

 Got response from Url www.facebook.com

 Url www.facebook.com, result OK

 Got response from Url www.stanford.edu

 Url www.microsoft.com, result OK

My expectation was the output should be in the below order since Parallel.Foreach block the calling thread until it completed. 

 Starting TestParallelForEach

 Got response from Url www.facebook.com

 Url www.facebook.com, result OK

 Got response from Url www.stanford.edu

 Url www.microsoft.com, result OK

 Parallel.ForEach Completed - True

 Ending TestParallelForEach

I reckon I am missing something here ....why doesn't Parallel.Foreach waits till all it's internal tasks(the Http call here) are completed ?

Comment: drop `async`: `url => {...}`

Comment: It looks like you aren't awaiting `ForEach` function. Also `Parallel.ForEach` is useless if it has `MaxDegreeOfParallelism  = 1`

Comment: @Shocky would be interesting to see how you implement your suggestion to "awaiting ForEach"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not suggesting awaiting foreach (but if you make a list of tasks and then waitall then it would be plausible), but since he has async function, it needs to be awaited to be able to get results he wants. I would probably go with different approach than this.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is neither async friendly, nor suitable for throttling I/O operations. Look here for proper solutions: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)